# NETLOGO: Using variable from previous tick

Tags: variables, netlogo, agent-based-modeling

is there some primitive for using value of variable from previous tick? I tried to compute variable of "price" for one agent and I mean to use formula which includes other agents' "price" variable but from previous tick.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no built-in way to do this in NetLogo. Your best bet would probably be to create a variable called something along the lines of `varname-last-tick` and then updating that as the last thing you do in the `go` procedure of these agents. It sounds like the variable you want to use for your agents is 'price', so it would be something like,

```
to agent-go
  do-stuff
  set price-last-tick price
end
```

then you can use `[price-last-tick] of other agents` in your code rather than the current price.

Comment: Yeah, Ive already figured that it could work this way. I appriciate your help anyway.