# update variables for next tick

Tags: variables, netlogo

I'm trying to model a battery storage in netlogo. I need to pass the battery remaining electricity calculate from one tick to next tick as the initial value until the simulation ends. 
I try to use method suggested by Arthur ([NETLOGO: Using variable from previous tick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370786/netlogo-using-variable-from-previous-tick)) but it didn't work.
Is there any way to do that in netlogo (version 5.3)?
Thanks!

My code looks like this:

```
 globals[ remaining-electricity-last-tick] 
 to go
 ifelse tick = 1 [ set remaining-electricity 0 ;; set initial storage zero ] 
                 [set remaining-electricity remaining-electricity-last-tick ] 
 ... 
 ... 
 ... 
 set remaining-electricity-last-tick remaining-electricity 
end
```

Comment: That is the correct approach.  What do you mean by "it didn't work"?  If the problem is that you have multiple "batteries", just use add an attribute instead of a global variable.
Also, please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for reply Alan.My code looks like this:              '  globals[ remaining-electricity-last-tick]

to go
  ifelse tick = 1
  [
    set remaining-electricity 0  ;; set initial storage zero
  ]
  [
    set remaining-electricity remaining-electricity-last-tick
  ]
  ...
  ...
  ...
  
  
  set remaining-electricity-last-tick remaining-electricity
end'                        If I run the model, the remaining-electricy  remains zero. Is it about the using of ifelse?

Comment: Code is very hard to read in comments — please edit your original question to include the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never change it from zero.  Let's rewrite what you have as follows:

```
to setup
  ;note: remaining-electricity-last-tick = 0 (default value)
  set remaining-electricity 0 ;; set initial storage zero
end

to go
  ;therefore you set remaining-electricity to 0
  set remaining-electricity remaining-electricity-last-tick
  ;therefore you set remaining-electricity-last-tick to 0
  set remaining-electricity-last-tick remaining-electricity
end
```

Comment: Thanks Alan,it works well when `remaining-electricity`and `remaining-electricity-last-tick` are defined as global variables; However when I define `remaining-ele` as a agent variable like this `breed [batterys battery] batterys-own[remaining-ele] globals [remaining-ele-last-tick] to setup ca ask batterys[set remaining-ele 0] end to go let ele-local 0 ask batterys[set remaining-ele ele-last-tick set ele-local remaining-ele].....(some procedure)..........set remaining-ele-last-tick ele-local`

Comment: the remaining-ele just didn't update, what could cause that?@alan

Comment: You are getting tangled in your program logic.  Here is a suggestion.  Do not use global variables unless absolutely necessary.  Use reporter procedures instead of command procedures whenever possible.  Post a new question if problems remain after you make these changes.