# Netlogo: Creating starting conditions for myvar-last-tick

Tags: netlogo, modeling

I'm trying to create a variable in Netlogo that changes based on its value last tick.  I've followed [this question thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370786/netlogo-using-variable-from-previous-tick) in how to create such a variable, but I'm having a bit of trouble creating the initial conditions, because at tick=0, there is no myvar-last-tick because there was no last tick, so Netlogo autosets myvar-last-tick to 0.  How can I create myvar and myvar-last-tick such that when tick=0, myvar-last-tick is the same as myvar only at tick 0?  To be clear I would like to program the variables such that they follow a pattern like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSZeM.png), although for my actual program the rate of decline would not be constant like in this example.

Answer (score 2):

Before you call your `go` procedure (i.e., your schedule), you should call a `setup` procedure.  Usually, the very first thing your `setup` procedure should do is all of your global-variable initializations (perhaps by calling a `setup-globals` procedure).  You can initialize `myvar-last-tick` and `myvar` to anything you like.  Just make sure the the result of your first call to `go` will produce the starting outcome you want.